# How to resolve tomcat version conflict in eclipse

Tags: tomcat

I imported a project which is works on tomcat 1.8 version but i am using 1.7 version how to make that project to working using tomcat 1.7 version.

Comment: No such versions of Tomcat. Can you clarify?

Comment: oopss sorry .. actually right now I am working on tomcat 7.0 version and I imported a project which is works on tomcat 8.0 version but I want to make that project work in tomcat 7.0 version only what to do?

Comment: project which is developed using tomcat 8.0 version is not working in tomcat version 7.0

Comment: Please define (very specifically) "not working". Nobody can read your mind.